# Cloning Queries in mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, functional-programming

I am trying to create a wrapper class around the mongoose query, that allows me to use the query in a more functional way. Whenever the user adds a clause like `where` or `limit` to that query, I want the class to clone itself and then apply the new clause to the cloned object. That way I could use the only and the new query and the old one is relyable as it never gets changed.

So far I could not find any solution that supports this.

```
class BaseMongoQuery<T> {
  constructor(private readonly query: mongoose.DocumentQuery<ReadonlyArray<T>, T & Document, {}> {}

  where(parameters: ParameterType<T>) {
    const newQuery = this.cloneMyQuery()
    newQuery.find(parameters)
    return new BaseMongoQuery(newQuery)
  }

  private cloneMyQuery() {
    // return clone of this.query
    // This is what I am looking for
  }

  getResults() {
    return this.query.exec()
  }
}
```

I know that I could write it differently and remember all the where clauses and limits and such, and only apply them at the end, but that also does not seem quite right to me.

Do anybody have a different idea and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks